# Using srcsets to load different images based on browser widths

Tags: images

I want it so that on a mobile breakpoint, the image in my function uses 'full' and on laptop/desktop it uses 'thumbnail'.

Here's a snippet of what I've got going on:

```
while ($sponsors->have_posts()) : $sponsors->the_post();
   $id = $sponsors->post->ID;
   $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $id );
   $img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $id ); // , 'full'
   $src_set = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $thumb_id );

   $html_out = '';
   $html_out .= '<img src="' . $img . '" srcset="' . $src_set . '" />';
endwhile;
```

The `srcset` appears empty though, not sure how to properly use this.

EDIT:
I've also tried doing it with
`$src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $thumb_id );` instead of `$img`, which also produces the same url, but `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset` still returns `false`.

Comment: Have you tried to `echo` what `$thumb_id` returns?

Comment: @SamuelAsor Yeah, it shows a number that's different from the post id. I dumped `$src` and using `$thumb_id` it was able to produce the url using the default thumbnail size.

Comment: Maybe 'medium' is not a valid image size within your theme, can you try `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $thumb_id,  'thumbnail' )` ?

or any other valid image size : 

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_intermediate_image_sizes

Comment: @Pabamato it exists, its the default, I see thumbnail, medium, medium-large, and large.

Comment: @Darren Can't tell too much but I would go for checking `wp_calculate_image_srcset()` and see when is the ´false´ being returned. Can you see the image in the media library?

Comment: @Pabamato not in the media library, but in the ftp I see in uploads all of the variant images that were made

Comment: @Darren not even the main one? I mean the diff ones should not be availables on the media library but the main one should be. Can you try re uploading the image for a given post and test?

Comment: @Pabamato Yes, main ones do appear in there.